# Injective function? Find a formula? Factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, divisor-counting-function

I need some help with the following question, thanks.

Let $$r : \mathbb N → \mathbb N$$ be the function where the output is the number of positive integer factors of the input.

For example, $$r (15) = 4\ \ (4\ \  positive\ \  integer\ \  factors\ \  of\ \  15)$$

Questions I am confused about:

$1)$ Is $r$ an injective function$?$

$2)$ If $n = p^k$, where $p$ is prime, and $r$ is a positive integer, find a formula for 
$r (n)$ .

Comment: Start with question 2. What are the divisors of $p^r$ when $p$ is a prime?

Comment: r + 1 is the number of divisors?

Comment: @Ladlad  That is correct.  For the first question, is it possible for two distinct integers to have the same number of factors?  Edit your question to include your thoughts on these two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ .  $r$  is  not  injective .  Since every  prime  number  has  $2$  positive  integer  divisors. $$r(p)=2$$  for  any  *prime*  $p$.

$2)$ . $$n=p^k$$ 
 Then  the  divisors  of  $n$  are  $$1=p^0,p=p^1,p^2,.....,p^{k-1},p^k$$

So  you  see  , there  are  $k+1$  such  divisors .

So,$$r(p^k)=k+1$$